# Java Desktop App Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, desktop-application, jxbrowser

I am working on a project of Geofencing simulation. I have done all my part as an Interactive application. Now, I need to deploy the application into a desktop. I am using eclipse IDE and JxBrowser for displaying the page and so on. I have placed my maps.html folder in src file of the Project. I cannot find the proper file path to access it. Though might seem simple, All I need to know is How do i  load the URL of the page which is not hosted.

```
browser.loadURL("???????????");
```

What should i mention in the above ? area

The file is located as maps.html in the same src folder as the class.

```
public class GoogleMapsSample {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

    Browser browser = BrowserFactory.create();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JxBrowser Google Maps");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(browser.getView().getComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setSize(700, 500);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.setVisible(true);

    browser.loadURL("???????????????????????");

  }
}
```

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: I did it . This is the code for Jxbrowser

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [file URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme):

```
browser.loadURL("file:///C:/path/to/your/file/maps.html")
```

Comment: I did that. But when I build my application in to a jar, I am getting portability issues

Comment: @user2512046 Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185592/open-an-html-file-inside-a-jar-file It will tell you how to load a file from inside a jar.